# Centering a countdown timer

Tags: html, css

I have been playing around with my countdown timer and now I can't center it again.
Is it something to do with my countdown css or am I missing `@main center` in the style?

I am very new to this so it has been a bit of a copy and paste exercise as well as understanding how to use it. Any recommendations in how I could improve this as well would be great!

```css
.live-widget {
margin: center;
display: flex;
color: #eee;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
width: 66%;}

body .flip-clock-wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;}

.live-widget .event-date-countdown{
 width: 100%;
text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);`#event-countdown{
  display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
max-width: 500px;
border-radius:8px;
background: rgb(0 0 0 / 28%);}`}

.counter-section{
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-color: #14203bbd;
background-blend-mode: darken;
padding: 1rem 0;}

#h-event-countdown{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
max-width:500px;
margin:center;
border-radius: 8px;
background: rgb(0 0 0 / 28%);}

.event-date-countdown > div, .counter{
font-size:clamp(1.5rem, calc(1.5rem + 3.5vw), 3rem);
color:#138bc1;
text-align: center;}

.event-date-countdown > div > div span{
display: block;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 16px;
color:#eee;
font-family: 'Mandali',sans-serif;
margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="live-widget">
  <style>
    @main center
  </style>
  <div class="event-date-countdown">
    <div id="event-countdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my countdown.js

```
// Set the date were counting down to

eventCountDown("event-countdown", "April 14, 2021 18:30:00");
eventCountDown("h-event-countdown", "June 3, 2021 09:00:00");

function eventCountDown(idName,time){
    let countDownDate = new Date(time).getTime();

  let x = setInterval(function() {

    let now = new Date().getTime();

    let distance = countDownDate - now;

    let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById(idName).innerHTML =
    `<div class="t-days">${days}<span>days</span></div>
    <div class="t-hours">${hours}<span>hours</span></div>
    <div class="t-minutes">${minutes}<span>minutes</span></div>
    <div class="t-seconds">${seconds}<span>seconds</span></div>
    `;

    if (distance < 0) {
     clearInterval(x);
  document.getElementById(idName).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}




$('.counter-head .counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },

  {
    duration: 3000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }

  });  



});
```

Here is the issue:
[image]

I will show screenshots of the code because it may be the way I entered it:

HTML:

[image]

CSS:

[image]

JS:

[image]

Comment: What is `@main center`?

Comment: `#h-event-countdown` ? I do not see this is in your html either... Also where is your countdown code?

Comment: @rayhatfield I am not sure whether a style is meant to be called from here or not

Comment: @dalelandry I did the countdown in JS I can add that in as well. Apologies for not adding in earlier

Comment: Hey @Stabbathehut , it would be so nice if you put all the codes together, so folks can help you better. use https://jsfiddle.net to have a working example. good luck :)

Comment: I just added ```style="width:100%;"``` to ```<div class="live-widget" style="width:100%;">``` and it's centered. see: https://jsfiddle.net/au9k0q54/

Comment: Hi @Kristian thanks for looking into this. Could it possibly be my indentation that is off?

Comment: There is no such  thing as `margin: center`. You need to do `margin: auto` To center a div that has `max-width`

Comment: Or you can do `justify-content: center` in #event-countdown

Comment: @Ajay the justify-content in 'event-countdown only pushes the text together